# Place one image on another and make area transparent using imagemagick

Tags: php, imagemagick

I have a white background and say a image "A" on it. I have another image "B", which i want to place on image "A"(image "B" 50% of image "A").

After placing the image "B" on "A", i need the area equivalent to image "B" gets transparent so i am able to see the white background.

How can i do it in php using imagemagick?

Comment: You mean an image mask? Have you looked at this? http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/masking/

Comment: i looked at it, but donno how to do it with php?

Comment: @dearlbry: Its like cut hole the size of image "B" in image "A", so i am able to see the bottom layer beneath image "A"

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve the above using the composite constant: DSTOUT in imagick.

```
$background->composite($overlay, COMPOSITE_DSTOUT, 0, 0);
```